# find the following integral

Tags: calculus

I really dont know why i got confused by this but i need assistance, it is school break and i am reading ahead. How would i get this?

I got the asswer to be -7 is this right? I have tried simplifing it and finally decided to to do it and found -7 but have no one to tell me if it is the correct answer. Can someone answer my question?

$\int_1^3{\rm}f(x) dx=5 $ and$ \int_3^7{\rm}f(x) dx=-12 $ find $\int_1^7{\rm}f(x) dx.$

Comment: Yes, $-7$ is correct. You obtain the answer by adding the integrals.

Comment: You're right. What part of the process is confusing to you?

Comment: simplifying it i got -7 but was not sure if i was right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to note this! as Dr. MV said.

$$\int_a^b f(x)dx+\int_b^cf(x)dx=\int_a^cf(x)dx$$

So to distribute it: this is how we get the $-7$;

$$\int_1^7 f(x)dx = \int_1^3f(x)dx + \int_3^7f(x)dx$$

This will be = $$ 5-12$$

and the correct answer is $$-7$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\int_a^b f(x)dx+\int_b^cf(x)dx=\int_a^cf(x)dx$$

Comment: Waoh, this is so straight forward. !  Thank you.

Comment: You're quite welcome. My pleasure.

Comment: And note we do not even need $a < b < c$ for this rule!

Comment: @gfauxpas Great point! +1 for that comment

Comment: @Dr.MV I got that answer and thought it was fair. :-0

Comment: I will upvote this. Through your exampler and her answer i got it right and i have understood this procedure. Thanks to you two.